# Material UI V 1.0.0 Grid Layout

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-design, material-ui

Trying to create a layout for a dashboard with a persistant drawer [here is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn7KJ.png)

So far added the side bar and top bar but the content is not displaying in the free space between. (body)

Should I be using the Grid resource to do this and say have the app header as the parent of the body. Or should I just create a seperate body that has margins to space away from the sidebar and nav. There seems it should be a smarter way where the components don't overlap each other than just adding margins etc.